# CURL as a download manager with multiple connections and progress display in PHP

Tags: php, curl, download

I wanted to use the CURL extension for PHP to create some sort of download manager and I was thinking if CURL allowed to implement these 2 features I'm thinking about:

1) Multiple connections or multi-part download just like a normal desktop applications download manager.

2) Constantly update on screen (text or graphical, doesn't matter) the download progress.

Does CURL for PHP allows any of this? If so, care to provide some hints?

Comment: PHP isn't really good at multitasking... you should consider using something else or you are probably signing for some pain ;-)

Comment: lots and lots and lots of pain!

Comment: @jldupont & Almosir:  Depends on how it is architected.  If you take advantage of the inherent nature web servers it's very easy to build a parallel, multi-threaded, distributed application.  There's no need to re-engineer what is already given you (which would still be doable (though painful) in PHP)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The curl_multi_xyz() functions, like [`curl_multi_exec()`](http://docs.php.net/function.curl-multi-exec) allow you to process multiple requests at the same time. Also take a look at [`CURLOPT_RANGE`](http://docs.php.net/function.curl-setopt) if you want to download multiple segements of the same file in parallel.
And the callback functions you can set with [`CURLOPT_READFUNCTION`](http://docs.php.net/function.curl-setopt) and [`CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION`](http://docs.php.net/function.curl-setopt) would allow you to send some kind of progress data to the client.

Comment: That is true, but you would have to init all downloads at the same time. When I think of a download manager I see stoping, starting, adding, removing, etc as functionality. Curl could not do this on its own, nor could php.

Answer (score 6):

To all the "PHP isn't great for multi-tasking" critics:

Take a step back and consider that you have an awesome Multithreading framework at your disposal if you're in a LAMP environment.  Use this base architecture to your advantage - i.e. Apache is the multi-threading manager - and a damn good one at that.

It is very easy to setup PHP to work in this environment.

> 1. Set max_execution_time = 0 to allow scripts to run indefinatly
> 2. Set ignore_user_abort = true to allow scripts to run even after the
>      client has aborted

Design light-weight single-task REST web services.  Design them in such a way that you don't care when they return such as in a queue type system. Writing to the queue is thread-safe and removing from the queue is thread-safe if done with some basic OS-level mutexes.

"forking" the web services is as simple as opening a file:

`fclose(fopen("http://somewebservice....php?a1=v1&a2=v2&...."));  // Launch a web service and continue...`

Not only is this approach multi-threaded, but it is inherently distributed as well.  The web service can be local or located on across the world.  PHP certainly doesn't care.

For a basic system the only thing that holds you back is the number of threads that apache allows.  Otherwise your code is ready to take advantage of load-balancing and all the other neat tricks that advanced Apache implementations have to offer.

Too often when developer think "multi-threaded" they think "OMG I have to handle forks and execs and waits and PIDs".  And if you design your system that way - you're right, it gets very complicated very quickly.  Step back and use what is given.  You've got access to directories?  Boom - you've got queues.  You can issue web calls?  Boom - you've got a multi-threaded (distributed) app.  Now just merge the concepts together as your app dictates.

Comment: The multithreading comments are against PHP. Not a stack. I agree with you, which is why I said it is possible in a variety of ways using more than just php, but this is absolutely sub-optimal from web service standpoint.

Comment: Bah, I just realized I voted down on accident. Edit your answer so I can change vote please :)

Comment: Sub-optimal in what way?  Server load?  He'll be waiting long for his Curl calls than for any sort of overhead parallel webservices create.  Sure you've got to use more than "just" PHP - the tools are there - use them.  Doesn't make it any less of a "PHP" solution.

Comment: Server load is not really the issue here. Connection limitations will come into play. This is why special servers were created for anything that needs long lasting concurrent connections between client and server. Also, you would be flooding the server with "http requests" in your method simply to emulate multi-threading in php when you could just choose a language that supports multi-threading and remove the hack. You can do it, sure, but there are far more optimal ways to accomplish the task. Then you would be given the tools to TALK to those child processes and get information from them in.

Answer (score 1):

PHP is not multi-threaded and, if you try to force it as such by means of multiple file calls or forking, the results are usually sub-optimal. I would suggest against this, HOWEVER, it would be possible to do something like this with a mix of js, php (probably not curl though but a custom php [file stream](http://us.php.net/stream)), and [long polling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology)

Comment: long polling on a busy site will consume your available webserver connection count quickly.  Not much else you can do with just php though.

Comment: Like I said, I suggest against it and it will be sub-optimal. But it is possible ;)

Answer (score 0):

It's possible, take a look into curl_multi_init();

Answer (score 0):

No, that is not case.  It is not possible because download manager calls the class that handles download 5 times - that is PHP class instance.

This is a sample class call:

```
$tr = new teConnections();
$data = $tr->downloadManager(array('http', 'host', path', 'login', 'pass', 'port'), 'file name, compression, streaming);
```